# Pass form validation as a parameter for ng-click method angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm creating multiple forms using ng-repeat and I want to pass every form validation as the second parameter of vm.validate function. It works well when ng-change is triggered but not when I press click button.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in data" ng-form="formName_{{$index}}">
<input type ="user.name" ng-change="vm.validate(user, formName_{{$index}}.$valid)"/>
<button ng-click"vm.validate(user, formName_{{$index}}.$valid)"/> click</button>
</div>
```

I get below error on pressing click button:

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 45 of the expression [vm.solderEcriture('debit',ecriture,formName_{{$index}}.$valid)] starting at [{{$index}}.$valid)].
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Basav's answer , to support the answer i have written a small jsfiddle. It makes use of ng-attr-name to bind dynamic variable fromName to the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/bishtneha/20ygxyLr/

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="formExampleCtrl as vm">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="user in vm.data" ng-init="formName = 'form' + $index">
      <form class="form-horizontal" ng-attr-name='formName' novalidate ng-submit="!formName.$invalid && vm.saveForm()">
        <input type="user.name" name="name" ng-change="vm.validate(user, 
               formName.name.$valid)" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click</button>
      </form>enter code here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the interpolation with a pure expression:

```
<!-- REPLACE this
<button ng-click"vm.validate(user, formName_{{$index}}.$valid)"/> 
     click
</button>
-->

<!-- INSTEAD -->
<button ng-click"vm.validate(user, this['formName_' + $index].$valid)"> 
     click
</button>
```

> #### Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:
>
> - It increases the complexity of the markup
> - There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.
> - It impacts performance, as interpolation adds another watcher to the scope.
> - Since this is not recommended usage, we do not test for this, and changes to AngularJS core may break your code.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of ng-attr-name like -

```
<div ng-repeat="user in data" ng-init="formName='FORM'+$index">
    <form ng-attr-name="formName" novalidate ng-submit="formName.$valid && vm.onSubmitClickHandler()">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
</div>
```